# Finding largest possible interval for which the integral exists

Tags: calculus

Let

$$ F(x,y) = \int\limits_x^y \frac{ d t }{\sqrt{ \alpha - t^2 }} $$

where $\alpha > 0$ and $x \leq y $, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Find the largest real interval $[x_{min}, y_{max}]$ for which integral exists and has finite value. Compute $F(x_{min}, y_{max})$.

#### Try:

My idea is to maximize $F$ subject to $\{ (x,y) : x \leq y \} $. Let $G(x,y) = y - x $. We have that

$$ F_x' = \frac{ - 1}{ \sqrt{\alpha - x^2 } }, \; \; \; \; F_y' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \alpha - y^2 } }   $$

So, $\nabla F = \lambda \nabla G = ( - \lambda , \lambda ) $ gives that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \alpha - x^2 } }  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \alpha - y^2 } }  $$

but, this does not seem to help. am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

The given integral equals $\arcsin({\frac{y}{\sqrt{\alpha}}})-\arcsin({\frac{x}{\sqrt{\alpha}}})$. As $\arcsin$ is defined for the interval $[-1,1]$, therefore the maximum interval for the existence of the integral equals $[-\sqrt{\alpha},\sqrt{\alpha}]$. The value of the integral is $\pi$ in the principal value range.